# I am having this error message in python, in a reddit video generator

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, reddit, moviepy

https://github.com/Shifty-The-Dev/RedditVideoGenerator is where this is from but it is closed so i cannot ask there

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\myname\Documents\Projects\Reddit\RedditVideoGenerator-master\main.py in line 90
     87     print(f"Total time: {endTime - startTime}")
     89 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 90     createVideo()

c:\Users\myname\Documents\Projects\Reddit\RedditVideoGenerator-master\main.py in line 23, in     createVideo()
     20 fileName = script.getFileName()
     22 # Create screenshots
---> 23 screenshot.getPostScreenshots(fileName, script)
     25 # Setup background clip
     26 bgDir = config["General"]["BackgroundDirectory"]

File c:\Users\myname\Documents\Projects\Reddit\RedditVideoGenerator-master\screenshot.py:14, in   getPostScreenshots(filePrefix, script)
     12 print("Taking screenshots...")
     13 driver, wait = __setupDriver(script.url)
---> 14 script.titleSCFile = __takeScreenshot(filePrefix, driver, wait)
     15 for commentFrame in script.frames:
     16     commentFrame.screenShotFile = __takeScreenshot(filePrefix, driver, wait,   f"t1_{commentFrame.commentId}")

File c:\Users\myname\Documents\Projects\Reddit\RedditVideoGenerator-master\screenshot.py:21, in __takeScreenshot(filePrefix, driver, wait, handle)
     19 def __takeScreenshot(filePrefix, driver, wait, handle="Post"):
     20     method = By.CLASS_NAME if (handle == "Post") else By.ID
---> 21     search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((method, handle)))
...
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16
```

is the error message.

The browser of the reddit post opens but nothing happens and then this message occurs.

I was expecting screenshots to be taken and the main file to run

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.